# Prepend url to all static resources in grails?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I created an app in grails called `xyz`, and I changed the war so created (`xyz.war`) to ROOT.war. The grails app context was also "/" now. I can access the app from root (ie `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://www.mywebsitedomain.com/`). All my `img src` tags are also absolute, for eg.
`<img src='/images/abc.png'>`
and ajax calls to an action are like this

```
$.ajax({
  url:"/myController/myAction/myId"
})
```

Everything runs fine.

Now I need to change the deployed war from ROOT.war to xyz.war. But all resources are absolute (they start with '/'). I cannot see any images, nor do any calls to controllers work, because they expect the `/xyz` before them. **Can I make a config change to do this?** I don't want to prepend the `/xyz` to all urls in my gsp and js files. Changing grails app context to `/xyz` has not helped, nor has appending `/xyz` to urlMappings.groovy in the `/$controller/$action` code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what I did, and you can decide if it is what you want to do. The first step is to change the grails contextPath to what it should be.

In my `main.gsp` that I use for all pages, I have this set in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var contextPath = "${contextPath}";
</script>
```

Then I use that variable in all of my javascript files that use hard coded paths. You shouldn't be using any hard coded paths in GSPs. You have tags to get those for you based on controller and action. If you need further explanation, let me know.

Comment: yes, but i have well separated .js and .gsp files. And since you cant use `<g:link>` tags within js files, i have to hardcode. As for your solution, yeah I guess thats what'll have to be done.